# How to detect IPv6 global address is deprecated or not?

Tags: embedded-linux, ipv6

I am able to detect all IP addresses but I want to detect which IPv6 addresses are deprecated. How can I do that using C code? May be in `/proc/net/if_inet6` is having that information but I am not sure about that fifth column in this file indicates that. Here is my `/proc/net/if_inet6` file.

```
fdc2714277b700009422b252a33ddc6a 02 40 00 21     eth0
fdc2714277b70000021a4dfffedd455f 02 40 00 00     eth0
00000000000000000000000000000001 01 80 10 80       lo
fe80000000000000021a4dfffedd455f 02 40 20 80     eth0
fdc2714277b70000ec3e4b537af7f419 02 40 00 01     eth0
```

In this fifth column which is having entry of **21** is my deprecated IPv6 address and entry of **01** in fifth column is my current temporary IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. That column is a hexadecimal value containing flags. The flags are defined in `rtnetlink.h`:

```
#define IFA_F_SECONDARY 0x01
#define IFA_F_DEPRECATED 0x20
#define IFA_F_TENTATIVE 0x40
#define IFA_F_PERMANENT 0x80
```

So the address with flags value 21 is a deprecated secondary address.

Comment: This indicates that these values are for ifa_flags in rnetlink.h file. Will these HEX values not clash with ifa_flags values as per their pre defined structure as per in if.h file or here for deprecated IPv6 address 0x20 indicates that IFF_NOTRAILERS flag is set?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. A flag fields just contains bits, and this is what those bits mean for this flag field.

Comment: I think ifa_flags is having specific significance for each bit which are defined in /linu/if.h file. According to that file, 0x20 means IFF_NOTRAILERS is set. So does it mean that, if IFF_NOTRAILERS is set, it indirectly indicates that it is deprecated IP address? Flags are defined under "enum net_device_flags" structure.

Comment: The `if_inet6` documentation specifies the values in `rtnetlink.h` are being used

Comment: I want to detect deprecated IPv6 using C code. I am detecting IPv6 address by opening socket. So if ifa_flags are same as these flags, I can detect it direct from there using socket. I may not require to open if_inet6 file.

Comment: ifa_flags defined under ifaddrs structure are different in comparison to if_inet6 file's flag for interface.